# What is HTML code that causes captions/comments pop up when mouse is rolled over a hyperlink?

Tags: html, mouseover, hyperlink

What is that peice of the HTML code that allows me to provide comments to links before the user is actually clicking on them?
Do you know what I mean?

I mean, on my web page I have some hyperlinks, and I want to know some information about it - what I will be taken to if I click on this link - so I just roll over my mouse on that link and a certain kind of caption appears providing me with all necessary info about this link.

I know how to make hyperlinks in HTML, but I have no idea how to make these self-popping -up captions. Can anyone, here , please share with me how to do that? Which tags do I need to use for that?

A simple example would be highly appreciated.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Title.

```
<a href="whatever.htm" title="This will cause a tooltip to appear">link</a>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are going for a `title` attribute then one problem is the default timeout for the  attribute. ie after a fixed time it will disappear.

If you want a tool tip that appears when the users mouseis over that and that does not disappear, then you can use css and javascript to make a tooltip.

**[Create a Nice, Lightweight JavaScript Tooltip](http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/javascript_tutorial/create_lightweight_javascript_tooltip/)**

Comment: WOW, Rahul, this link that you gave me is just wonderful, but the problem is I am only familiar with HTML, I have never tried JavaScript before. 
Do you think I could incorporate that piece of JavaScript in your example into HTML code with no sudden setbacks?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are referring to the [abbr](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_abbr.asp) tag

The title attribute gives the normal yellowish tooltip.

Comment: Well, I was talking about a hyperlink, but your answer taught me something new, though! Thank you.